# Got mired in a selective DELETE statement on a single table in t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

Say, I have a table like this (SQL Server 2008):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (ID INT, dtIn DATETIME2, dtOut DATETIME2, Type INT)

INSERT tbl VALUES
(1, '05:00', '6:00', 1),  -- will be removed
(2, '05:00', '7:00', 1),  -- will be removed
(3, '05:01', '8:00', 1),
(4, '05:00', '8:00', 1),
(5, '05:00', '6:00', 2),  -- will be removed
(6, '05:00', '7:00', 2),
(7, '05:00', '7:00', 3),
(8, '04:00', '7:00', 3)
```

I need to remove all records of the same 'type' (if 2 or more are found) with the same 'dtIn' for their 'type', except the one with the largest 'dtOut'. In other words, the table above should result in this:

```
(3, '05:01', '8:00', 1),   -- no matching 'dtIn' for 'type' = 1
(4, '05:00', '8:00', 1),   -- largest 'dtOut' for 'type' = 1
(6, '05:00', '7:00', 2),   -- largest 'dtOut' for 'type' = 2
(7, '05:00', '7:00', 3),   -- no matching 'dtIn' for 'type' = 3
(8, '04:00', '7:00', 3)    -- no matching 'dtIn' for 'type' = 4
```

How do you even select several rows with the equal type from the same table. You can't do select * from tbl where type=type.... Anyway, I'd appreciate some help with this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way to select the rows you want to delete:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl T1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl T2
    WHERE T1.Type = T2.Type
    AND T1.dtIn = T2.dtIn
    AND (
            T1.dtOut < T2.dtOut
            OR (T1.dtOut = T2.dtOut AND T1.id < T2.id)
        )
)
```

This query can also be easily changed to actually delete the rows. Just change `SELECT *` to `DELETE T1`. But please do test that it does what you want before actually running the delete statement.

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ff87/38)

---

**Update**

Here's an approach using ROW_NUMBER:

```
;WITH T1 AS (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type, dtIn
                                  ORDER BY dtOut DESC, ID DESC) AS rn
    FROM tbl
)
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM T1
    WHERE rn > 1
)
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1ff87/36)

Comment: Listen, how is it even humanly possible for you to do something within literally 10 seconds of me posting it, when I've been working on this the whole morning???

Comment: @ahmd0: Lots of practice! The first time I had to do something like this, it took me quite a while too. :-)

Comment: No, seriously, Mark, how do you learn all this stuff? Is there a special book that teaches you this... Because it's not just a plain programming skill.

Comment: @MarkByers ... hmmm lot of practice + [this cv](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/markbyers/)

Comment: i like `EXISTS` but never used it in a correlated way like this answer. need to remember this.

Comment: @MarkByers: Really quick, Mark. The actual selection works, but the DELETE sub as you suggested results in "Incorrect syntax near 'T1'" But I'm assuming that one can do DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id IN(<your select>) right?

Comment: @ahmd0: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it. Use `DELETE T1`.

Comment: @MarkByers: I hate to bring this issue back, after doing more tests it doesn't seem to handle the duplicate rows correctly. I see your logic in using T1.dtOut < T2.dtOut but it should actually be T1.dtOut <= T2.dtOut, which unfortunately will break the condition of leaving only 1 record with largest dtOut... Sorry

Comment: @ahmd0: If they have a different ID you can use that as a tie-breaker. I'll update my answer. You could also use `SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type, dtIn ORDER BY dtOut DESC, ID DESC) FROM yourtable` and delete rows that have row number higher than 1.

Comment: ID is a primary index, so yes, they do have a different ID... So let me study your correction now. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkByers Can you update it for the delete statement btw? Again it's way over my league, but if I replace first SELECT * with DELETE T1 it removes the entire table.

Comment: @ahmd0: I posted an sqlfiddle showing that it works for your original data. If you think it doesn't work for some other data, can you update the fiddle and post it back here?

Comment: @MarkByers: Thanks. New sample SQL, hmmm. Which one would you prefer? They both work.

Comment: @MarkByers: I checked your 1st SQL, and shouldn't "OR (T1.dtOut = T2.dtOut AND T1.id < T2.id)" be "OR (T1.dtOut = T2.dtOut AND T1.id <> T2.id)"?

Comment: @ahmd0: It means "If the type, start and end are all the same, then delete the lower id." So I think `T1.id < T2.id` is correct. As to which to use: pick the one you understand best. You may also want to test their performance if that could be an issue.

Comment: @MarkByers, yes, the 1st one doesn't work. I updated it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d8db/2

Comment: @MarkByers: My bad... I was still using it with my "not equal" addition in the last OR condition.

Answer (score 1):

not very elegant (+ the conditions are the same as Mark's answer) but it's an alternative.

[Fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a19ac/1)

```
;with my_cte(ID)
as
(
  SELECT T1.ID
  FROM 
      tbl T1
      JOIN tbl T2 on
        T1.Type = T2.Type
        AND T1.dtIn = T2.dtIn
        AND T1.dtOut < T2.dtOut
  )
select *
from tbl t
where not exists 
              (
              select 1 
              from my_cte c 
              where t.ID = c.ID
              )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Queries for Duplicate Rows**

I just saw that you can have duplicate rows. So:

```
DELETE X
FROM
   (SELECT Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Type, dtIn ORDER BY dtOut DESC) Item, *
   FROM #tbl) X
WHERE Item > 1
```

Note that this version above doesn't need a join so should perform better than all other queries on the page.

or

```
DELETE T
FROM #tbl T
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM #tbl T2
      WHERE
         T.dtIn = T2.dtIn
         AND T.Type = T2.Type
      ORDER BY T2.dtOut DESC, T2.ID DESC
   ) X
WHERE T.ID < X.ID
```

or

```
DELETE T
FROM #tbl T
   INNER JOIN #tbl T2
      ON T.dtIn = T2.dtIn
      AND T.Type = T2.Type
      AND (
         T.dtOut < T2.dtOut
         OR (T.tdOut = T2.dtOut AND T.ID > T2.ID)
      )
```

**Queries for no Duplicate Rows**

If you couldn't have duplicate rows (except for ID) then it would be simpler:

```
DELETE T
FROM #tbl T
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM #tbl T2
   WHERE
      T.dtIn = T2.dtIn
      AND T.Type = T2.Type
      AND T.dtOut < T2.dtOut
)
```

or even

```
DELETE T
FROM #tbl T
   INNER JOIN #tbl T2
      ON T.dtIn = T2.dtIn
      AND T.Type = T2.Type
      AND T.dtOut < T2.dtOut
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, duplicate records are possible, so you short versions won't work.

Comment: @ahmd0 Two more versions added

Answer (score 0):

Mine is a little different from @Mark's, but I believe it should get you the same results (only because I assume that `id` is unique):

```
DELETE a
FROM dbo.tbl a
WHERE id <> (
    SELECT MAX(id)
    from dbo.tbl b
    WHERE a.type = b.type
      AND a.dtIn = b.dtIn
)
```

Comment: Sorry, sqlfiddle.com doesn't seem to return the correct result with your query. It's way beyond my knowledge to correct it though...

Comment: Hmmm. Strange, now it does. Sorry, I'm not sure why it gave me a different result... maybe because I'm heckuva tired. Thanks for your input too!

Comment: Actually, I just realized that this code assumes that a higher `id` also means a higher `dtOut`, which may not be the case.  It'd probably be safer to change the `id`s in that statement to `dtOut`s (if that matches your reality).

Comment: @bhamby: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow you. Can you correct your actual SQL. Also note that it should do deletion and not just selection. I also found out that Mark's code doesn't seem to handle duplicate dtIn and dtOut's. Read my comment to his post above... ding it! Back to the drawing board. But at least I know what your guys' logic is now...

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE     
(  
ID INT,  
newno int  
)   

insert @table  
SELECT T1.ID,   
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type, dtIn
                              ORDER BY dtOut DESC, ID DESC) AS newno  
 FROM tbl T1      

 select *  
from tbl t
where t.ID IN
             (
              select ID from @Table where newno > 1
              )
```