# How to avoid duplicate records in left join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables t1 & t2. In t1, there are 1641787 records. In t2, there are 33176007 records. I want to take two columns from t2 and keep everything of t1 using a left join. When I use left join with t1 to t2, I got more records than t1. I would like to get a similar number of records as t1 after joining. Please give me a suggestion. There are many to many relationships between the tables. Here is my code:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.City
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results It is unclear how you want to handle rows from `t1` that match on several rows in `t2`.

Comment: A database tag might also be useful: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: first of all, are you sure that the relationship between these 2 tables are 1 to 1 and not 1 to many?

Comment: big query. there are several columns that are matching between the tables.

Comment: Already answered here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586923/select-distinct-with-left-join-ordered-by-in-t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586923/select-distinct-with-left-join-ordered-by-in-t-sql)

Comment: @Watth . . . That is an inappropriate "duplicate", given that it is for a very different database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate `t2` *before* joining:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.City
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t2.ID, ANY_VALUE(t2.City) as City
      FROM t2
      GROUP BY t2.ID)
     ) t2
     ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Comment: Is there a reason for a downvote on a correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

"select **destinct** ..."
  add a "order by"

Like this:

```
SELECT DESTINCT t1.*, t2.City
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY t1.name ASC;
```